# Google charts - histogram: extra bars appearing alongside data

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, histogram

I'm using Google's [histogram](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram) functionality in JavaScript to graph the output of a stochastic model, and it's overlaying extra bars on top of an otherwise nice chart.

The chart is generated by running the `calculate_display_coverage()` function hundreds of times with different inputs. I assure you the inner workings of the function aren't a problem here (I can't really post my whole Fiddle, but I show what the data look like in my code snippet).

```
gender = {
    gender1: "Male",
    gender2: "Female"
};
device = {
    device1: "Tablet",
    device2: "Mobile",
    device3: "Desktop"
};
var paramstring = "";

resultArray = [];
resultArray[0] = ['Run','Coverage'];
var q = 1;

for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    for (var y in gender) {
        for (var w in device) {
            for (var z = 1950; z < 1980; z++) {
                paramstring = "09/21/";
                paramstring += z.toString();
                resultArray[q] = [q,calculate_display_coverage('SIW', y, paramstring, w).displayed];
                q++
            }
        }
    }
}

// dataset looks like [['Run','Coverage'],[1,80000],[2,42000],...]

google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(resultArray);

    var options = {
        title: 'Model output by coverage',
        legend: { position: 'none' },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

With HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
</script>

<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
```

In this case, where `x = 100`, the histogram includes these extra bars[image: extra bars shown in 100 meta-run chart]

Somewhat different formatting but same issue for more runs, where `x = 2000`.

[image: extra bars shown in 100 meta-run chart]

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that both columns of your data are numeric. Currently it has the format

```
[['Run','Count'],[1,80000],[2,42000],...]
```

So the histogram is including the index values as datapoints. You need to cast them as strings, so in the above code, the statement should be

```
resultArray[q] = [q.toString(),calculate_display_coverage('SIW', y, paramstring, w).displayed];
// [['Run','Count'],['1',80000],['2',42000],...]
```

That will remove the extra bars.